# What is locked when update or deleting in a table without primary key in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have table without primary keys and I need to perform some update or delete operations on it while other processes might add new rows and change other rows. In order to asses problems with data integrity and threadlocks I want to know if anything or everything is locked when not having primary keys?

Hope you can help me

Comment: Postgres only locks the rows you UPDATE.

Comment: But based on the documentation it uses the primary key to do it. So what if there are no primary key?

Comment: It uses whatever `where` clause you used to limit the update to the rows you want to change